# How do I resolve unhashable type error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to load three .mat files in a single matrix. All of them are 1024*1024*120. But I am repeatedly getting an unhashable type error. I even used 'del' to delete each file after loading it in the matrix. What can I possibly do to resolve this error?

Following is my code :

```
import scipy.io 

import numpy as np
mat = np.zeros((1024,360))

x = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/prakriti/Project/A.mat')                 
mat[:,0:120]= x[240,:,:]
del x                                                                
y = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/prakriti/Project/B.mat')
mat[:,120:240]= y[240,:,:]
del y
z = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/prakriti/Project/C.mat')
mat[:,240:360]= z[240,:,:]
del z

import matplotlib.py as plt
imageplot = plt.imshow(matrix)
```

Following is the error :

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/home/prakriti/Project/p.py", line 8, in 
> > >           mat[:,0:120]= x[240,:,:]
> > >       TypeError: unhashable type

I have been given a .mat file which is 1024*1024*360 i.e., a 3D object. I have divided the data in to three .mat files A,B and C. All three of them are 1024*1024*120. I am loading them to a matrix 'mat' which is 1024*360. I am loading each one of them one by one and then deleting them to make space. Basically it's just a 2D slice of the 3D object at the point 240. Later I am trying to plot the image. But I am repeatedly getting either hashable type error or memory error.

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Including the full traceback.

Comment: Can you print the complete value of x and update that in the op?

Comment: Matrices are not hashable since they are mutable. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the type of `x`? ScyPi loads matlab `struct`-Data as python dictionaries, and `:` is not hashable:

```
x = {}
x[:] -> TypeError unhashable type
```

You probably want to extract the correct field of the struct first:

```
data = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/prakriti/Project/A.mat')
x = data['x'] # depends on the structure of A.mat                 
mat[:,0:120]= x[240,:,:]
```

Comment: You have to look into the actual `data`. I cannot know in which structure you saved your mat-files.

Comment: File "/home/prakriti/Project/p.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/prakriti/Project/A.mat')                 #Load .mat file into dictionary x
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 152, in loadmat
    matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 270, in get_variables
    hdr, next_position = self.read_var_header()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 223, in read_var_header
    stream = BytesIO(dcor.decompress(data))
MemoryError

Comment: What do you mean by structure?

Comment: Okay, I tried to find the structure of the .mat file. It says:  name: 'A'
          size: [1024 1024 120]
         bytes: 1.0066e+09
         class: 'double'
        global: 0
        sparse: 0
       complex: 0
       nesting: [1x1 struct]
    persistent: 0

Comment: You have to examin the structure of the data in Python not in Matlab; or how did you save the matrix `A` in Matlab?